# Series of dicom images into specific format in matlab

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have series of matlab images which belong to a single patient. I found some code online, but it is sowing some error. I want something like this, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWp1C.jpg)

Here is the code I have.

```
% Preallocate the 256-by-256-by-1-by-20 image array.
X = repmat(int16(0), [256 256 1 20]);
% Read the series of images.
for p=1:20
filename = sprintf('brain_%03d.dcm', p);
X(:,:,1,p) = dicomread(filename);
end
% Display the image stack.
montage(X,[])
```

I found this code from here:
https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/accessing-data-in-dicom-files.html

```
Error using montage>validateColormapSyntax (line 339)
```

An indexed image can be uint8, uint16, double, single, or logical.

```
    Error in montage>parse_inputs (line 259)
    cmap = validateColormapSyntax(I,varargin{2});

   Error in montage (line 114)
  [I,cmap,mSize,indices,displayRange,parent] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

  Error in Untitled2 (line 9)
  montage(X,[]);
```

Comment: And the error is....what?

Comment: @excaza  `Error in Untitled2 (line 9)
montage(X,[]);`

I used this example along with their given dataset.

Comment: Please [edit] the *full* error message and stack trace into your question.

Comment: @excaza i have updated the question along with the eroor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for calling the [`montage`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) function has changed since that code sample was written (back in 2002!). As noted in the comments section of the [File Exchange submission for the sample DICOM data files](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2762-dicom-example-files), the new correct syntax is this:

```
montage(X, 'DisplayRange', []);
```

You were getting that error since the new syntax interprets `montage(X, []);` as if `X` were an indexed color image (which isn't allowed to be a signed `int16` type, according to the error) with an empty color map `[]`.

Comment: It worked. However, I have on question in the following line

`filename = sprintf('brain_%03d.dcm', p);`

How do I change it for the random file names in the folder? I mean it is taking the series of images named as `brain_01d.dcm` to `20` but i have different names for each dcm file. what should i do?

Comment: please help me with this one

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: Since I don't know how your files are stored or named, I can't give specific help. You should start by checking out the [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function.